# can't get value from checkbox sibling input

Tags: jquery, input, siblings

I'm having a hard time getting a value from the sibling of a checkbox. My click function sees the checkbox click, but then I get undefined for my variable. It doesn't matter if I declare it with var. I've tried siblings, children, children of siblings, with and without "input[name=info]" What's the obvious thing I'm missing? Thanks for the help.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charliemagee/eBZ9G/

```
<ul class="goalsinprogress goalsection">
  <li class="inprogress">
    <span class="goaltitle">study after dinner</span>
    <span class="goalstatus"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
    <span class="gatherinfo"><input type="text" name="info" class="info"/></span>
  </li>
  <li class="inprogress" data-info="['66','77']">
    <span class="goaltitle">keep locker tidy</span>
    <span class="goalstatus" data-goal="keep locker tidy"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
    <span class="gatherinfo"><input type="text" name="info" class="info"/></span>
  </li>
</ul>

$(".goalsinprogress").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "click", function() {
  var newinfo = $(this).siblings().children().val();
  return console.log(newinfo + '  what the');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the li parent and then [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `input.info`:

```
$(".goalsinprogress").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "click", function() {
  newinfo = $(this).closest('li').find('input.info').val();
  console.log(newinfo + '  what the?');
  return updateStatus = 'completed';
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bhML/1/)

Comment: Perfect. First time to use closest. Thanks very much!